# nodemailer not sending inside mocha test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, nodemailer

I declared this in routes:

```
router.get('/test',userController.test);
```

The function in the userController is declared this way:

```
exports.test = function (req, res) {
    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: myuser,
            pass: mypass
        }
    });

    const message = {
        from: 'me@gmail.com',
        to: 'other@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Subject here',
        text: 'Text here',
        html: '<html><body><div>html here</div></body></html>'
    };
    console.log("message:",message);
    transport.sendMail(message, function(err, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(info);
        }
    });

    res.status(200).json({
        test: 'test'
    });
};
```

Now, when I start the app with

```
node app.js
```

then I receive the mail in my inbox.
Also, the "info" in the console is printed:

```
message: {
from: 'me@gmail.com',
to: 'other@gmail.com',
subject: 'Subject',
text: 'text here',
html: '<html><body><div>hmtl here</div></body></html>'
}   
{
  accepted: [ 'other@gmail.com' ],
  rejected: [],
  envelopeTime: 174,
  messageTime: 374,
  messageSize: 675,
  response: '250 2.0.0 OK  1575235049 y6sm13785566ljm.95 - gsmtp',
  envelope: {
    from: 'me@gmail.com',
    to: [ 'other@gmail.com' ]
  },
  messageId: '<somehash@gmail.com>'
```

So that looks good.
However, when I run this through mocha, no mail arrives in the inbox. And no info is printed in the console.
As you can see, if there was an error it should be printed. But it is not printed either.
But when running the test, I see in the console the result of

```
console.log("message:",message);
```

But still no mail is sent. It looks like the sendMail-function is never reached/executed.

What could the issue be?
The test module is simply calling the test-endpoint (there are other endpoints called here and all of them are executed):

```
//This test is green
it("Succedes when test", done => {
chai
  .request(app)
  .get("/users/test")
  .end((err, res) => {
    expect(res).to.have.status(200);
    done();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually these kind of Problems result from an uncaught exception or uncaught Promise rejection. An error simply does not show up because of this.

In your case you don't seem to check the `.end` callbacks `err` parameter for errors.
Try checking the `err` for non-existance first.

```
expect(err).to.not.exist
```